# "Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwidgets" amazon linux AMI qt5.6 installation

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, webkit, qt5

I tried to install qt5.6 on amazon linux AMI and run webkit for dryscrape python running , but always has the error when install webkit 
"Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwidgets" .

There's no way I can find a webkitwidgets library for amazon linux AMI which is CentOS . But just for ubuntu version such as

"sudo apt-get install libqt5webkit5-dev"

Is there any way I can locate webkitwidgets library for amazon linux AMI instance ?

Comment: The webkit modules were removed from Qt 5.6: see the [release notes](http://wiki.qt.io/New_Features_in_Qt_5.6#Removed_Modules).